# how can I partially block the vector? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I create two threads that work with the same vector, since I pass the vector by reference. my task is to block part of the vector with the first thread so that the second thread can work with the unblocked part of the vector. for example, the first thread blocks the second half of the vector, and the second thread, blocking the first half of the vector, works with it

Comment: If you passed two integers by reference to two threads (instead of two halves of a vector), how would you handle this?

Comment: if the threads do not resize or push elements, or more generally do not invalidate any iterators, then there is nothing to be "blocked". And if they do then blocking the first or second part wont be sufficient

Comment: please clarify the question by adding more details. If possible post a [mcve]

Comment: So your question is basically "how do I tell a thread which half of a vector to process?"?

Comment: Looks like you need some basic data structure that will hold which thread handles which part. This data structure has to be thread safe. Some kind of scheduler can fill this data structure, and the worker threads can query it for their part.

Comment: If by "works with it" you mean "inserts things" then there is a problem because vectors are one continuous piece of memory and if they need to be reallocated to fit more in the WHOLE vector is reallocated.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
My whole question boils down to blocking some part of the vector so that no one can access it. That is, no one can either read elements from this area or write in it.